# Is the equation $y = f(x)$ a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By definition, a differential equation is an equation that involves a function and its derivatives. In the equation $y = f(x)$, a function $f(x)$ is involved. But is this a differential equation since $f(x)$ is the zeroth derivative of $f(x)$?

Comment: I think that would be an unusual use of the term.

Comment: If a constant function can be called a function, then this should also be called a differential equation.

Comment: What's the motivation for this question? Is there a problem you're having trouble solving because of this?

Comment: @Karl I'm teaching calculus to engineering students, and I told them that the equation $y=f(x)$ is a differential equation since it involves the zeroth derivative of the function. But the faculty seems to think that this is not the case since they gave out a quiz, one item of which asked which of the following equations is a differential equation. One of the equations is of the form $y=f(x)$, which is incorrect according to the answer key.

Comment: I see. Too bad they put a question like that on the quiz, testing a fairly useless edge case of a term that doesn't really have or need a precise definition. Terms like "real number" and "derivative" need precise definitions because they're mathematical objects, but "differential equations" is arguably just a natural-language term describing a class of math *problems* and *techniques*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y = x^2$ is a differential equation just as much as $x = 5$ is an equation. As in, technically it fulfills all the formal requirements, but it looks strange and seems more like a finished solution.

Comment: One might call it a degenerate DE.